# START/STOP MEDIAPLAYER android studio

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Play / stop button - how to make music play back from the beginning? Stop function not pause function
``

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    b_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_play);
    b_play.setEnabled(false);
    b_play.setText("Loading");


    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view ) {
            if (started) {
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                b_play.setText("PLAY");
            } else {
                started = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                b_play.setText("STOP");
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: There's a `stop()` method too.

Comment: the stop method works, but the music cannot be restarted
you must exit the application

Comment: Ah, yes. You'd need to create a new `MediaPlayer` again after `stop()`. (No need to exit the app.) But the `seek()` method in the answers of course makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Call `mediaPlayer.seekTo(0)` after `mediaPlayer.pause();`

```
b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view ) {
            if (started) {
                started = false;
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                b_play.setText("PLAY");
            } else {
                started = true;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                b_play.setText("STOP");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you called stop() ? Can you try adding this code in the else {} block: if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    }

Comment: can you show me the whole ready code?
after pressing stop, discards from the application

Comment: What is the stack trace of the crash ?